# Verification of answer

Tags: solution-verification, permutations

Suppose there are *9* delegates from each country including A, B, C, D.
(*i*) If they were to sit in a row such that A,B sit next to each other but C,D don't,find number of such possible permutations.
Supposing A,B to be a single unit,
we get that there are $8!\times 2$ ways to make A and B sit together. Out of these, some arrangements have C and D together while others don't. Let us now find the number of arrangements in which A and B are a single unit and C and D are a single unit.
This would give rise to $7!\times 2 \times 2$ ways to do so.

By subtracting the number of ways in which A and B and C and D sit together from the number of ways in which A and B sit together we get $8!\times 2-7!\times 2 \times 2$ ways to sit them in the required arrangements.
(*ii*)Find the number of ways to sit them around a circle following the pattern in (*i*).
Here, we do the same as we did in case (*i*), but now under circular permutations, we get
the answer $$7!\times 2-6!\times 4$$.
Please help me know if my answers are correct or not.

Comment: Yes your answers seem correct.

Comment: I find the wording confusing. Are A, B, C, D countries, or delegates? From your work, I suppose the latter, but then what do you mean by "from each country"? If each country is supplying 9 delegates, that suggests there are more than one country and therefore more than 9 delegates in total.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Actually there are 9 delegates in total.